# Local Database in Silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I want to integrate a local database into Windows Phone 7 project. The DB should be allready filled with values from manual input.
Therefore I use a wizard to create a local Database in WPF.
I can create tables, set their values and fill in them, but I could not find the way how to refere columns from different tables.

Is it possible using UI wizard in Visual Studio or only possible by coding the datacontext?

Comment: It's not clear whether you're trying to use WPF or Windows Phone 7 - it can't be both.

Comment: Have you looked into using Entity Framework at all?

Comment: maybe something like this will work http://sviluppomobile.blogspot.com/2010/03/sqlite-for-wp-7-series-proof-of-concept.html

Comment: @Jon: it can be both, using sqlmetal. it converts the wpf db into winpho, generating whole DataContext. The only thing one need to do is to remove some not supported methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible what you ask and the easiest way to do it is Linq to Sql.

[Database Management in Mango](http://www.barebonescoder.com/2011/07/wp7-dev-database-management-in-mango/)

There is an easier way to do it but i think ms doesn't support that, you create a new windows WPF project and there you add a LinQ to SQL database model there you can create your database and then just copy it to your wp7 project and include it in the solution.

Then you will have to comment out or delete the two constructors which are not supported by the WP7 and your are ready to use your database.

The two constructors to comment out use *System.Data.IDbConnection connection*

[This solution is explained in detail in Corrado's Blog](http://blogs.ugidotnet.org/corrado/archive/2011/06/05/using-local-database-in-wp7-mango.aspx)